# Laravel 5.2: how to get Model properties in a Controller

Tags: laravel-5

How can I access a Model's properties in a Controller in Laravel?

In my User model I have this array:

```
protected $sortable = [
    'first_name',
    'last_name',
    'email',
];
```

Then, in my UserController I have:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
...
use App\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        // here I'd like to get the $sortable array
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your index function, you can access it by

`$this->sortable`

In order to do that, **you must to change property accesibility** to public:

```
public $sortable = [
    'first_name',
    'last_name',
    'email',
];
```

If you insist on `protected` accesibility, you can create a getter function with in your model.

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if i understood you well, but if you have first name, last name and email in ur DB, you can get them like this:

```
$user = User::all();
```

If not, just create it:

```
 $user=new User();
```

Comment: Nope, I want to access the $sortable array that is in my Model (like $fillable), so that I have a list of 'secure' fields that I can use to dinamically sort columns (if a user try to sort by 'username', or worst tries to inject malicious SQL, then he is catched)

Answer (score 0):

User model

```
public $sortable = [
    'first_name',
    'last_name',
    'email'
];
```

UserController controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
...
use App\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {

        /* user object */
        $user = new User();

        foreach ( $user->sortable as $item )
        {
            echo "{$item} <br />";
        }

    }
}
```